# Create Elements Thru Javascript MessUp

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a `<div><div><div><input type="text"></div></div><div>` via javascript. But somehow, the code seems to be not working. I have tried to use DOM methods to create the above mentioned but nothing seems to work. Please Help!!

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function newFunc2()
   {
    a=document.createElement('div');
    b = document.createElement('input type="text"'); 
    a.appendChild(b);

    c=document.createElement('div');
    c.appendChild(a);

    var d=document.getElementById('new1');
    d.appendChild(c);
   }
   </script>
   </head>

  <body>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="ChangeCase" onclick="newFunc2()"/>;

  <div id="new1">
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
b = document.createElement('input'); 
b.setAttribute("type","text"); // Here you can set radio,checkbox according to need
```

instead of

```
 b = document.createElement('input type="text"');
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7EKzJ/)

To specify the type of the input you can have the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

**Docs:**

[`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

Comment: `b.setAttribute('type','text')`

Comment: `b.type = "text";` is sufficient, `setAttribute` is longer and unnecessary.